# In GraphViz, in a strict graph, is it possible to have 2 edges between nodes if they have different attributes?

Tags: graphviz

What I want to achieve is, if I have something like

```
Strict Digraph G {
   a -> b [label = edge1]
   a -> b [label = edge2]
   a -> b
   a -> b
   a -> b [label = edge1]
}
```

then I should get a graph with 2 nodes and 3 edges between them (One with label edge1, one with edge2 and one without a label).

It doesn't seem to be possible, with the strict keyword with this input, it only draws one edge.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not "legal".  From https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

> A graph may also be described as **strict**. This forbids the creation of multi-edges, i.e., there can be at most one edge with a given tail node and head node in the directed case.

Comment: yeah that's what I suspected, i've settled on a solution that involves some pre processing (making sure duplicates aren't put in the DOT file) and then removing the strict keyword